# RN4870 Prepare write request and Execute write request

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Android App that write several bytes to a Bluetooth device.
Looking on btsnoop_hci.log I see that, when a large amount of bytes are sent to the BLE device, the app use Prepare Write Request more times and then Execute Write Request: Immediately Write All.
Now my problem is how to perform this with a my application using a RN4870 module.
At this moment I can connect, read service and characteristics, and write using
CHW command as described in the manual when the there are few bytes.
But I cannot write as the remote BLE device expect when there are  lot of bytes.
Thank You for support
Marco

Comment: Do you really have to use Prepared Write/Execute Write Request? It is very inefficient. A much better option would be to increase MTU so you can send everything in one Write Request or Write Without Response. With MTU >= 515, you can write and read each attribute in one single packet.

Comment: Hmm I read the manual and it seems to be far from feature complete...

Comment: Emil thanks for your comment.
If I could I would not use Prepared Write/Execute Write Request.

Comment: Emil thanks for your comment.
If I could I would not use Prepared Write/Execute Write Request.
Because I don't know how to do. The problem is that the remote BLE works so, I bought to commands lights and really i don't know if is it possible to change MTU, and above all I don't know why the manufacturer decided to use this solution (Remote BLE is a RF51822). I will check if is possible to apply your suggestion.
P.S. When You say I read manual you are talking about RN4870?
RN4870 is BLE 4.2 so should be able to execute Prepare Write Request

Comment: I meant the RN4870 manual. And according to its declaration at https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/showCorePICS.cfm?3A000A5A005C534C535B5014403B0C0D0E2405022413010E57503F202A5A7558534057 it doesn't support long writes in client mode (see "Table 3: Generic Attribute Profile Feature Support, by client" under Generic Attribute Profile Support). But it should support MTU negotiation so you should ask the manufacturer how that is done.

Comment: Ok I will ask to microchip about this.
Another problems is that seems that NRF51822 not support the MTU change reading on internet

Answer (score 0):

This is the Microchip answer:

Hello,

The core specifications are handled by the firmware.
The user doesn't have access at this level, so is nothing you can set.

Regarding the long data question:
"Does RN4870 module support the Data Length Extension feature? "
RN4870 rev 1.28 support DLE, but partially. The normal packet size in BLE without DLE is 20 bytes. 
With a standard DLE feature, the normal packet size should be 251 bytes. 
However, in RN4870 Rev 1.28, the packet size is 151 bytes. So it is not a full implementation of the DLE.

The DLE feature (Data Length Extension) is embedded into the lower levels of the Bluetooth stack and there are no specific commands to enable or disable DLE. Essentially, if the peer device also supports DLE, then the DLE will be enabled. 
So there are no specific (commands) that you need to do to increase throughput through DLE.

Regards,

In other words there is nothing to do!

Comment: The MTU is a (G)ATT thing. It has nothing to do with DLE. DLE is just a thing that allows larger packet fragments over the air...

Comment: With DLE feature packet size shouldn't be exactly 251 bytes. Specification says it can be up to 251 bytes. So the packet size of 151 bytes is correct. In Android you don't have to enable DLE feature. Use the GATT API to set the MTU size, it will internally set the LE data length(based on controller capability and peer device capability).

Answer (score 0):

In Android Application you can't directly set the DLE length, instead you should set the MTU size. Android Bluetooth stack will calculate DLE length based on the MTU. Maximum Data Length supported by BT protocol in 251, but can be between 27 and 251 depends on BT controller H/W capability. During connection BT Device will negotiate with peer device(If peer device support DLE) to set Maximum DLE size supported by both device.

To increase your throughput you can use the maximum supported MTU size of 512. Also you can write without response and do error check on data using your own logic like checking parity or CRC and re-transmit data from Application for better throughput.